# If statement not working with document.querySelector

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am basically working with a hamburger menu. At this stage, I have made a menu and when it is clicked, a cross will appear instead of it. It is all working well.

```js
function drop(){
let bars = document.querySelector("div.bar");
let cross = document.querySelector("div.cross");
bars.style.display = "none";
cross.style.display = "flex";
}
```

```css
div.bar {
    display: flex;
    transition: 1s;
    cursor: pointer;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 30px;
    color: gray;
}

.ibar {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 40px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 31%;
}

.cross{
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: fit-content;
    font-size: 70px;
    color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar" id="bar" onclick="drop()">
    <div class="ibar"></div>
    <div class="ibar"></div>
    <div class="ibar"></div>
</div>
<div class="cross" id="hiddenCross">&times;</div>
```

**But the main problem I am facing is below:**

In my function, when I add an if statement like this:

```
if (cross.style.display === "none"){
    bars.style.display = "none";
    cross.style.display = "flex";
}
```

then the two lines of code inside the `if` block (which are changing display properties) are not working.

I first thought it is some kind of property of `document.querySelector` which is restricting this kind of behaviour. But when I used the id's to execute the same function, the same problem persists.

Comment: toggle a class, so much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style property of elements only checks inline styles. Use `getComputedStyle` instead so that all CSS rules will be found.

```js
function drop(){
let bars = document.querySelector("div.bar");
let cross = document.querySelector("div.cross");
if (window.getComputedStyle(cross).display === "none"){
bars.style.display = "none";
cross.style.display = "flex";
}
}
```

```css
div.bar {
    display: flex;
    transition: 1s;
    cursor: pointer;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 30px;
    color: gray;
}

.ibar {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 40px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 31%;
}

.cross{
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: fit-content;
    font-size: 70px;
    color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar" id="bar" onclick="drop()">
    <div class="ibar"></div>
    <div class="ibar"></div>
    <div class="ibar"></div>
</div>
<div class="cross" id="hiddenCross">&times;</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you click on the hamburger, drop() function fires and inside this function you set style.display property of "cross" element to flex. But the code inside if statement will be executed only when style.display property of "cross" element is set to none, but it happens never.
You can just use any additional class, for example, "hidden" and toggle it every time you click on menu:
when bar has class "hidden" - cross should have this class and vice versa .
And in the css file class "hidden" should have display: none property.

Comment: Read the last few lines of the question. When the function fires, it first checks the display property and if it is none (which is none by default) and then changes its display to flex.